# Send multiple files with one PHP, not at the same time

Tags: php, xml

Not sure how to word my question, but this is it:

I have an XML with 1000 products that I need to upload. I can only upload 100 products at a time with PHP. How do I make one PHP upload 100 products at a time until all products are uploaded?

Currently, my solution is to have 10 PHP files and 10 XML files each with 100 products. I would prefer if I can do this with 1 XML and 1 PHP file.

The reason I cannot do more than 100 products is that the sever I am uploading to doesn't allow me to more than 100 per instance.

I am using `simplexml_load_file` to load the files in the PHP

This is my code so far:

```
<?php 
$data = Array();
$xml=simplexml_load_file("products_1.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
foreach ($xml->product as $pr) {
  $data[] = Array
  (
        "id" => (int)$pr->identifier,
        "name" => (string)$pr->name,
         ...
  );
}

// username & password
#$data = array_slice($data, 1,10);
#$data = $data[20];
$username = '...';
$password = '...';

//create hash
$hash = base64_encode($username . ':' . $password);
$headers = array(
   'Authorization: Basic ' . $hash
);

// send data with cUrl
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://.../api/product/save');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array('data'=>($data))));

$result = curl_exec($ch);

// decode response
$all=json_decode($result);

// print array response
echo '<hr>';
echo '<pre>';
print_r($all);
echo '</pre>';
//echo '<hr>';
?>
```

For the other PHP files, I just replace the `products_1.xml` with the next number

Comment: Well, if you can define boundaries for your data in terms of range offsets, a cron job can do pretty well. A multiple curl request option exists to do this parallely, but I am not sure how well it can do.

Comment: `chunk` the data into manageable blocks and process each chunk